.NET8 vs .NET Core 3.1 compatibility
Is it ok to create a test project in .NET 8 for an application that targets .NET Core 3.1?
If no, should both be 3.1?
I have an existing application that targets .NET Core 3.1 and now want to add testing.

If no, should both be 3.1? - No - both should be .NET 8 - .NET Core 3.1 is beyond dead and deprecated .....

ok thanks for your response.
